# Java Continuous Integration without Server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

There are a couple of Continuous Integration servers available for Java ([Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)).

In my understanding these are quite 'UI'-centric in that the main way to interact with these solutions is through a web interface. Also, they require a Servlet container to run and start a couple of processes on the server.

I would like to know whether there is a Continuous Integration solution available for Java/Maven/git that can run without a server and can be controlled from the command line. For instance, by issuing a command:

```
CLIIntegrationSolution path/to/git_repo
```

Which checks if there are any updates on the repo, builds the project if required, runs the tests, generates reports, and sends messages in case of any build or test errors.

I know this can be hand-crafted but it might take some time to get it right.

Comment: If you run test from console, what do you need e-mail notifications for? All you want could be accomplished with a simple bah script.

Comment: yep, I'm just not too sure about how 'simple' the script would be. Essentially, with the point about Email I wanted to point to the need for some easy way to do reporting. It could also be done by updating a set of XML/HTML files (eg with a list of all projects and their status).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[could have been a comment, but just too long ]

You should go back check what you really wants to do. Jenkins has embedded web server , does not require an app server.  It also exposes [command line](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)  to do almost every thing from start stop and reconfigure build.  It also exposes a web service layer for [programmatic query](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

In short jenkins will do what ever you want. The GUI part is only to setup, not for actually performing the task. They are all done by scheduled/scm poll /manual triggers.

Comment: Thanks, [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) looks very useful!